# How do I categorise JSON data with PHP?

Tags: php, html, json, parsing

I want to categorise my JSON data by the ID under 'categories'. Right now I can manually change what I want displayed in the if statement but I want it to be done by the actual user.

I want to be able to display just JSON data with categories->id = 1/2/3. Is there a way to be able to select for example only 'general' or 'cleaning' blog posts through a button maybe?

```
<?php

$json_file = file_get_contents('posts.json', true);

$json = json_decode($json_file);

$posts = $json->posts;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Blog</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        if($post->categories[0]->id == "1"){
?>
    <div>
        <h2><?php echo $post->title; ?></h2>
        <p><?php echo $post->date; ?></p>
        <p><?php echo $post->content; ?></p>
        <p><?php echo $post->categories[0]->slug; ?></p>
    </div>

<?php
}}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the JSON data

```
{
"posts": [
    {
        "title": "My Lovely Blog",
        "date": "22nd September 2018",
        "content": "Hey guys so this is my brand new blog that I will be posting on weekly! Stay tuned for more :)",
        "categories": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "slug": "general"
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        "title": "How to clean your home fast: 10 spring cleaning tips",
        "date": "29th September 2018",
        "content": "Declutter your home: There is a simple rule you can use to declutter you home. If you have not used something...",
        "categories": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "slug": "cleaning"
            }
        ]
    },


    {
        "title": "7 Fashion Trends to Be Thankful for This Year",
        "date": "24th November 2018",
        "content": "The trickle down effect of this trend might take a while, but on the runways, office-appropriate clothing got a serious makeover. Blazers were paired with embellished short shorts at Prada and loose, 90s-inspired trousers at Tom Ford. At Celine, daywear was rendered in sherbet colors while Michael Kors topped off plunging tops and sarong sequin skirts with wide-cut blazers and flip flops. Just because you have gone corporate does not mean you cannot have fun.",
        "categories": [
            {
                "id":3,
                "slug":"fashion"
            }
        ]
    }
```

]
}

Thanks for any help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Without mixing javascript into the solution, you could add a button that takes you to the same URL but with a query string parameter:

```
<a href="/?filter=cleaning">Show Cleaning</a>
```

Clicking this would take you to the same page, but you would now be able to grab the 'filter' key value from the `$_GET` global variable:

```
foreach ($posts as $post)
{
  if($post->categories[0]->slug == $_GET['filter'])
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Using the above method, you could add any number of buttons that apply any number of filters you would like on the page.

EDIT: The above solution assumes you are on the base URL, if that page is on a URL like `/blog/`, your href would be `/blog/?filter=cleaning`